# Cocos2d JS HTML5

Tags: cocos2d-js

I want to rotate this image in cocos2d Java-script HTML5.
Upper and lower circles are two different sprites.
I am using this code:

```
var RotationAmount=0;
Top=cc.Sprite.create("Assets/Top.png");
Top.setPosition(MidX,MidY+100);
Top.schedule(function(){
    if(RotationAmount>360)
        RotationAmount=0;
});
    this.addChild(Top);
```

Here's how my sprites look:

[image: Sprites]

The above this causes my sprite starts to rotate around itself. I want to make it rotate around a point, so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

```
var Top = cc.Sprite.create("Assets/Top.png");
var rotateAction = cc.RotateBy.create(0, 1);

 Top.attr({
     x: MidX,
     y: MidY,
     anchorX: 0.5,
     anchorY: 0.5
 });

Top.schedule(function() {
  Top.runAction(rotateAction);
});

this.addChild(Top);
```

Comment: Good answers provide an explanation, not just code. Could you edit this to explain why it resolves the problem?

Comment: thanks user2351606......it works....
please tell a little more description about your code !

Comment: I create action 'rotateAction' for rotate sprite by 1 degree. Set for sprite attributes: (x,y) - position, (anchorX, anchorY) - point for rotation. And run action for sprite.